# What cms/ecommerce cart is store.barackobama.com run on?

Tags: shopping-cart

What shopping cart / ecommerce cms does [http://store.barackobama.com](http://store.barackobama.com/) use?

I'm curious as to see what shopping cart his team uses.

P.S. I'm not trying to advocate any affiliation or allegiance; as i feel political opinions are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://store.barackobama.com uses "Magento"

Comment: How did you know? The login url?

Comment: @ChrisJ.Lee One indication on a quick glance: in the source code there are javascript variables like "Mage.Cookies.path" – "Mage" is a typical magento variable.

Comment: You can use BuiltWith to find out this information -http://builtwith.com/store.barackobama.com